# How can I have different 404.js pages in a nextjs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm working on a nextjs project that uses pages subfolders and next rewrites to work with them

```
/pages
  /sitea
  /siteb

/config
  /sitea
  /siteb
```

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/sitea/',
      },
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: '/sitea/:path*',
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

Then each app instance loads a specific directory according to my `.env`. This is done through `next.config.js`

```
let config = require(`./config/${process.env.APP}/next`)

module.exports = {
  ...config
}
```

This is working very well with pretty much every scenario, except for the custom 404 page. I need a sitea-specific 404 page as well as a siteb-specific 404.

Adding `404.js` to `/pages/sitea` doesn't do the trick as `404.js` is expected to be in `/pages`. I tried adding another rewrite to the config:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/',
        destination: '/sitea/',
      },
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: '/sitea/:path*',
      },
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        destination: '/sitea/404',
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

to load `/pages/sitea/404.js` however, that still seems to be loading the second rewrite. Do you have any idea of how I can accomplish this?